# Algebra's exercise about algebraic extension of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Could you help me with this exercise?

> Let $\alpha \in L:K$ with $L$ algebraic over $K$ and let $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in GL_2(K).$$
>   Let $\beta=\frac{a \alpha+b}{c\alpha+d}$. Prove that $K(\beta)=K(\alpha)$ and find an expression for $m_{\beta}(x)$.

I found that $\alpha=\frac{b-\beta d}{c\beta-a}$ and I tried to use it to understand how $m_{\beta}$ is made but I didn't manage to.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: You should first show what you've done and where you're stuck at. Hint: can you express $\alpha$ in terms of $\beta$?

Comment: @egreg I tried to express  $\alpha =\frac{b-\beta d}{c\beta - a}$ but I don't understand how to use it in $m_{\alpha}$

Comment: @AlessioCangini Add that to your post to help stave off close votes.  *Always* add your relevant work to your posts.

Comment: @schwieb thanks

Answer (score 1):

- $K(\beta) \subseteq K(\alpha)$ because $\beta \in K(\alpha)$
- $K(\alpha) \subseteq K(\beta)$ because $\alpha \in K(\beta)$ since that matrix is invertible